Windows への MySQL インストール時に unknown variable 'mysqlx_port=0.0' エラーで落ちてしまう
WindowsへのMySQLインストール時にunknown variable 'mysqlx_port=0.0'のエラーで落ちます。
WindowsにMySQLをインストールし、MySQL Server 5.7.44を導入しました。
インストールにはインストーラーを用いてMySQL Server 5.7.44のインストールまでは完了しましたが、セットアップのところでエラーを吐いて落ちます。
原因はわかりませんか？
エラー：
unknown variable 'mysqlx_port=0.0'

My.iniを編集して、この行をコメントアウトや3306や33060に変更して保存し、Executeを押して再開しましたが、My.iniが初期の状態で再生成され、同じエラーで落ちます。
また、MySQLのサービス自体をコマンドから立ち上げようともしましたが、以下のエラーで落ちます。
エラー文：
MySQL57 サービスを開始します.
MySQL57 サービスを開始できませんでした。

サービスはエラーを報告しませんでした。



インストールに関してこんな記事が見つかりますが、インストール時に何を選択したのかとか、どんな作業手順を行っていて、どこの時点でエラーになったのかとか、細かい情報を追記した方が良いと思われます。MySQL Server 5.7 を Windows にインストールする手順, MySQL 5.7 セットアップ手順と関連情報, MySQLの開発環境を用意しよう（windows）, 4.2 MySQL Shell セッション MySQL 5.7 では、X プラグイン を手動でインストールする必要があります。, 設定ファイル(my.ini)の作成と配置 あとYahoo知恵袋にも質問しているようですが。

丁寧にありがとうございました。
バージョンが悪かったようで解決できました。
ちなみにすべてデフォルトの選択のままインストールしてました。

自己解決です。
入れようとしていたMySQLのバージョンが悪かったようで、
MySQL Server 5.7.44
ではなく、
MySQL Server 8.0.37
のインストーラーを取って、インストールすると正常にインストールできました。
本当はMySQL Server 5.7.44が必要でしたが、MySQL Server 8.0.37で代用できないか模索します。
